# Link tbb library with qtcreator with a cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, tbb

I have a cmake project and i'm using qtcreator 4.5 to develop on a Ubuntu environment. Right now i try to use the TBB library to parallelize my code but i get this error on compilation:

```
/usr/include/tbb/parallel_for.h:87: error: undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::~task_group_context()'
```

From what i understand I'm not linking my TBB library, is that the problem ? If yes, how to do so ?

EDIT 1: I installed TBB trough the command sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev, so i am not sure where it is installed, but there is a libtbb.so in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, is that it ?

EDIT 2: I founded the solution, I didn't have to go through th cmake files because I am adding the library path through Qtcreator. I founded the lib in /usr/include. 
So, if you have the same problem you can link your library by going to projects section in Qtcreator, the find TBB in the window and give the path of your lib.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Comment: Thanks, but my library is installed with "sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev" so i don't really know where it has been deployed on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you have installed the developnment lib in your Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev
```

The next step should be link in the .pro file against the tbb lib (-ltbb)

In my case, also I am working "indirectly" with tbb lib and I am setting the next lines in my .pro file for a static compilation:

```
## OTHER LIBS
LIBS += -L/myopencvpath/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib
LIBS += -lIlmImf -lippicv -llibjasper -llibjpeg -llibpng -llibtiff -ltbb -lzlib
```

Also this entry could help you: [how to get Threaded Building Blocks working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616064/how-to-get-threaded-building-blocks-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)

I hope this helps you.

EDIT1: I am so far away of being a cmake expert, but you could try something like this:

```
IF ( USE_TBB )
    MESSAGE( STATUS "Including TBB on MyLib build" )
    FIND_PACKAGE( tbb REQUIRED )
    LINK_DIRECTORIES( ${LIBRARYPATH} )
ENDIF ()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so fast. I already installed libtbb-dev, but i am working with a cmake project and not qmake (even if i develop with qtcreator). That's why i don't have a .pro file.

Comment: @tony497, let me check tomorrow if I have some cmake project linking against the tbb. I should, but I am not sure at all just now. :)